# CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() hangs

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I'm observing hang in `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` when one of the async is in an active loop.

Full code:

```
static async Task doStuff(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        // await Task.Yield();
        await Task.Delay(-1, token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
    }

    while (true) ;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var main = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var csource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var task = doStuff(csource.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Spawned");
            csource.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        }
    });
    main.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Prints `Spawned` and hangs. Callstack looks like:

```
ConsoleApp9.exe!ConsoleApp9.Program.doStuff(System.Threading.CancellationToken token) Line 23   C#
[Resuming Async Method] 
[External Code] 
ConsoleApp9.exe!ConsoleApp9.Program.Main.AnonymousMethod__1_0() Line 34 C#
[External Code]
```

Uncommeting `await Task.Yield` would result in `Spawned\nCancelled` in output.

Any ideas why? Does C# guarantee that once-yielded async would never block other asyncs?

Comment: re: your commented code, `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.MaxValue, token)` throws an argument exception so never hits your `while (true)`, so you wouldn't hang with that. `Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan` would be the appropriate argument for your intention.

Comment: >> your commented code, await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.MaxValue, token) throws an argument exception so never hits your while (true)
right

Comment: >> where to start; can start with pointing to the documentation, where it's said that `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` can switch contexts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CancellationTokenSource` does not have any notion of task scheduler. If the callback wasn't registered with a custom synchronization context, CancellationTokenSource will execute it in the same callstack as `.Cancel()`. In your case, the cancellation callback completes the task returned by `Task.Delay`, then the continuation is inlined, resulting in an infinite loop inside of `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`.

Your example with `Task.Yield` only works because of a race condition. When the token is cancelled, the thread hasn't started executing `Task.Delay`, therefore there is no continuation to inline. If you change your `Main` to add a pause, you'll see that it'll still freeze even with `Task.Yield`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var main = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var csource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var task = doStuff(csource.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Spawned");

            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Give enough time to reach Task.Delay

            csource.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
        }
    });
    main.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Right now, the only way reliable to protect a call to `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` is to wrap it in `Task.Run`.

Comment: thanks, haven't heard about continuations inlining opt. Strange, that there are no additional interfaces like `ConfigureAwait` for `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`

Comment: @nyaapa Well I submitted that to at least have a way to cancel a token without any kind of inlining: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23716 but it didn't get much traction

Comment: I had this problem just now and solved it with `CancelAfter(0)`, I have no idea what and why Cancel has to wait for, it's just that, set `IsCancellationRequested` to true and carry on, why does it have to hang?